# How to see detailed logs of all activities of GCP Firestore in Cloud Logging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

For any operation performed in Firestore DB like creating Firestore instance, creating collection, adding documents, adding/deleting fields, etc.. how can we see all the operations performed in Cloud Logging.

By default it gives only instance creation logs but not the CRUD operations.

```
*[
  {
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "status": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Error; please try again later."
      },
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "anubhav.kumar@....com"
      },
      "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "168.149.187.2",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
        "requestAttributes": {
          "time": "2021-12-20T17:15:19.476045Z",
          "auth": {}
        },
        "destinationAttributes": {}
      },
      "serviceName": "firebasedatabase.googleapis.com",
      "methodName": "google.firebase.database.v1beta.RealtimeDatabaseService.CreateDatabaseInstance",
      "authorizationInfo": [
        {
          "resource": "projects/..",
          "permission": "firebasedatabase.instances.create",
          "granted": true,
          "resourceAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "resourceName": "projects/..",
      "request": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.database.v1beta.CreateDatabaseInstanceRequest",
        "validateOnly": true,
        "parent": "projects/..",
        "databaseInstance": {
          "type": "DEFAULT_DATABASE"
        },
        "databaseId": ""
      }
    },*
```

Answer (score 0):

By default indeed only administrative operations are added to the audit log. If you also want to log data for regular data manipulation and retrieval, you can [enable those from the audit logs page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable).

Comment: Yes that is enabled but still the changes to collection or document or any field add/remove/update - exact data is not showing in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for Firestore audit logging suggest you'll need to enable these:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging